# Error in ocr of MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use `OCR` of MATLAB for some text recognition.This is part of my code-

```
r = ocr(n1,'TextLayout','Word')
if strcmp(r.Text,char('_'))==1 | strcmp(r.Text,char('/'))==1 
        figure,imshow(n1);title('False image to be removed');
else
        n2=imadd(n2,n1);figure,imshow(n2);title('uuu1');
end
```

This was my `ocr` result-

```
r = 

  ocrText with properties:

                      Text: '/

'
    CharacterBoundingBoxes: [3x4 double]
      CharacterConfidences: [3x1 single]
                     Words: {'/'}
         WordBoundingBoxes: [315 133 16 9]
           WordConfidences: 0.7857
```

So,the text recognized is `/` so it should have gone into the `if` part of my code.But it always goes into the `else` part.How can I fix this?

Comment: As far as I can see, there are spaces at the end in r.Text that you have to erase before checking. Or just check the first character.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this was the problem.I was missing out the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, there are spaces at the end in `r.Text` that you have to erase before checking. Or, just check the first character of `r.Text`.

To remove trailing and leading white space from a string, you can use:

```
str = strtrim(r.Text)
```

To only address the first character you can use:

```
r.Text(1)
```

So your line would be one of the following:

```
if strcmp(strtrim(r.Text),char('_'))==1 | strcmp(strtrim(r.Text),char('/'))==1

if strcmp(r.Text(1),char('_'))==1 | strcmp(r.Text(1),char('/'))==1
```